# Why are the rounding functions S4 generics rather than S3?

Tags: r, rounding, r-s4, r-s3

I was surprised to discover in the documentation for the rounding functions, e.g. `round`, that they are all S4 generics. What benefits does this grant them over being S3 generics? As best as I can tell, everything that they do can already be done equally well if not better (I think that S3 dispatch is faster than S4?) in S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ceiling`, `floor`, `round`, `signif`, and `trunc` are all *internally* generic functions.  You will not find corresponding generic function objects (of type `"closure"`, calling `UseMethod` or `standardGeneric`) in the **base** or **methods** namespace, because dispatch happens entirely in C code for efficiency.  The same can be said of the usual arithmetic, mathematical, logical, and relational operators.

You can define both S3 and S4 methods for, e.g., `round`, and both can be dispatched.  We already know about the S3 methods `round.Date` and `round.POSIXt`:

```r
> round.Date
function (x, ...) 
{
    .Date(NextMethod(), oldClass(x))
}
<bytecode: 0x13130e7e8>
<environment: namespace:base>
> identical(round(.Date(0.1)), .Date(0))
[1] TRUE
```

And it is not too hard to devise an S4 method:

```r
> setClass("zzz", contains = "character")
> x <- new("zzz", "0.1")
> round(x)
Error in round(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
> setMethod("round", "zzz", function(x, digits = 0) round(as.double(x)))
> round(x)
[1] 0
```

Hence the statement in `?round` to which you refer

> These are all (internally) S4 generic.

is a bit misleading.  It says that you can define S4 methods for `round` and that they are dispatched in C code, which is true, but it fails to express that you can *also* define S3 methods for `round` and that those are *also* dispatched in C code.

I'll refrain from answering your broader question about the benefits of S4 over S3, because it has been discussed at length elsewhere (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590656)).  Besides, that discussion doesn't really apply to internally generic functions like `round`, which are implemented exceptionally for speed.